# How to filter a QuerySet based on whether the objects in it are present in another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a QuerySet called time_slots which contains objects of model class TimeSlot.

```
time_slots = <QuerySet [
<TimeSlot: Room: Number: 1, category: Regular, capacity: 4, advance: 12, manager: anshul, from: 01:00:00, till: 02:00:00>,
<TimeSlot: Room: Number: 1, category: Regular, capacity: 4, advance: 12, manager: anshul, from: 04:07:00, till: 06:33:00>,
<TimeSlot: Room: Number: 1, category: Regular, capacity: 4, advance: 12, manager: anshul, from: 09:22:00, till: 10:55:00>
]>
```

models,py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    class Meta:
      ordering = ['number']
    number =  models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000), MinValueValidator(1)],
        primary_key=True
        )
    CATEGORIES = (
        ('Regular', 'Regular'),
        ('Executive', 'Executive'),
        ('Deluxe', 'Deluxe'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=CATEGORIES, default='Regular')
    CAPACITY = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
    )
    capacity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=CAPACITY, default=2
        )
    advance = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=10)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models. CASCADE
    )

class TimeSlot(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['available_from']
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    available_from = models.TimeField()
    available_till = models.TimeField()

"""class used when a user books a room slot."""
class Booking(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_in_date = models.DateField()
    timeslot = models.ForeignKey(TimeSlot, on_delete=models. CASCADE)
```

Each time slot can be either booked or vacant. In order to find if it is booked or vacant, I do the following-

```
if request.session['occupancy'] == '':
    for time_slot in time_slots:
        try:
            Booking.objects.get(check_in_date=request.session['date'], timeslot=time_slot)
            time_slot.occupancy = "Booked"
        except Exception:
            time_slot.occupancy = "Vacant"
elif request.session['occupancy'] == 'Vacant':
    for time_slot in time_slots:
        try:
            Booking.objects.get(check_in_date=request.session['date'], timeslot=time_slot)
            time_slot.delete()
        except Exception:
            time_slot.occupancy = "Vacant"
elif request.session['occupancy'] == 'Booked':
    for time_slot in time_slots:
        try:
            Booking.objects.get(check_in_date=request.session['date'], timeslot=time_slot)
            time_slot.occupancy = "Booked"
        except Exception:
            time_slot.delete()
```

I have to render the timeslots in the HTML according to its occupancy status which can be either Any (''), Booked or Vacant.

I know the above code will not work but I just wanted to tell the logic. I want to know how can I render the time_slots in the HTML based on occupancy?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the following should solve your issue.
It'll add an "occupancy" field on each TimeSlot depending on whether a linked Booking exists at the given date.
This occupancy field will be used for filtering if needed

```py
my_date = request.session["date"]
timeslots = TimeSlot.objects.annotate(occupancy=Case(When(booking_set__date=my_date, then="Booked"), default="Vacant"))
my_occupancy = request.session["occupancy"]
if my_occupancy != "":
     timeslots = timeslots.filter(occupancy=my_occupancy)
```

NOTE: `booking_set` in `booking_set__date=my_date` is the default [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name). You should probably override it

```py
class Booking(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_in_date = models.DateField()
    timeslot = models.ForeignKey(TimeSlot, on_delete=models. CASCADE, related_name=timeslots)
```